# Heat equation solution is dilation invariant proof

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, partial-derivative, heat-equation

Show that if $v(t,\|x\|)$ solves the heat equation on the set $Q \subset (0,+\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^n$, then the function $v(\lambda^2t,\lambda\|x\|)$ solves the heat equation on the set $Q_\lambda=\{(t,x)\in (0,+\infty)\times\mathbb{R}^n:(\lambda^2t,\lambda\|x\|)\in Q\}.$

My attempt: Let $w(t,x)=v(\lambda^2t,\lambda\|x\|)=v(f_1(t),f_2(x)).$ Then by applying the chain rule to obtain the partial derivatives we get
$$w_t(t,x)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial f_1}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}=\lambda^2\frac{\partial v}{\partial f_1}$$
$$w_{x_i}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial f_2}\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}=\lambda\frac{\partial v}{\partial f_2}x_i(x_1^2+...+x_n^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$w_{x_ix_i}=\lambda(x_1^2+...+x_n^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\partial v}{\partial f_2}-\lambda x_i^2(x_1^2+...+x_n^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{\partial v}{\partial f_2}+\lambda^2x_i^2(x_1^2+...+x_n^2)\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial^2 f_2}$$

which gives us
$$\triangle_xw=\lambda \frac{1}{\|x\|}\frac{\partial v}{\partial f_2}-\lambda \frac{1/}{\|x\|^2}\frac{\partial v}{\partial f_2}+\|x\|^4\lambda^2\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial^2 f_2}$$

I'm not sure this is the right approach since plugging the above into the heat equation doesnt satisfy it.

Comment: $$w_{x_{i} x_{i}} = \dots + \lambda^{2} x_{i}^{2} (x_{1}^{2} + \dots + x_{n}^{2})^{\color{red}{-1}} \frac{\partial^{2} v}{\partial f_{2}^{2}}$$ and check what you have written for the expression for $\Delta_{x} w$ after summing $w_{x_{i} x_{i}}$ over $i$.

Comment: After fixing the mistakes you pointed out I arrived at $\triangle_xw=\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial^2 f_2}\lambda^2=\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial^2 \lambda \|x\|^2}$ and $w_t=\frac{\partial v}{\partial f_1}\lambda^2=\frac{\partial v}{\partial \lambda^2 t},$ which for $(t,x) \in Q_{\lambda}$ satisfies the heat equation, is this correct? @MatthewCassell